# JSF 1.2 Populating multiple - select box entries dynamically

Tags: jsf, foreach, jstl, selectonemenu

I need to display components and data dynamically. Below code I am trying to populate list of select boxes. Trying to populate values from `var` within `forEach`.

```
<c:forEach items="${bean.dynamicParamsBean.editableComoBoxes}" var="editableComboBox">
    <h:selectOneMenu value="#{editableComboBox.param}">
        <f:selectItems value="#{editableComboBox.dataProvider}" />
    </h:selectOneMenu>
</c:forEach>
```

This works fine except `f:selectItems` where my select box is not populating any data. `editableComboBox.dataProvider` returns list of `SelectItem` objects.

This exact code works fine if I don't use loop and in turn `var`, directly populating select box values by referencing to `bean`.

Is there any workaround and alternative to resolve this issue?

Comment: I think you forgot to past the mentioned code.

Comment: Code in the [mcve] sense